# Is it possible to get a list of all users on a computer with LanDesk?

Tags: users, landesk

Is there a way to use LanDesk to query all of the user accounts on a given computer?

Comment: Have you tried asking LanDesk support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little fuzzy on the exact menu options since it's been a while, so you'll need to forgive the lack of exact detail.

It's not in the inventory by default, but it is in a different option in the right-click menu on a device to manage the local users and groups for the node.

If you just need to inventory the data, you can feed it into a node's inventory to the "Custom Data" inventory tree by instructing the client inventory to gather the data (add it to the ldappl3.template file and re-push the client).  Looks like there's some tools out there for this exact case; something like [this](http://www.droppedpackets.org/systemmanagement/ldms/inventory/extending-inventory-with-unmodeled-data-free-ad-groups/) seems to be right along the lines of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of LANDESK (9.6) and newer, you can get this information in the Inventory record of the individual machine.

You will find it under 'Local Users and Groups'. In there you will find both information about local users, as well as domain users who are members of various local groups.

Additionally there is an option in the general Network View to allow you to select users and identify the machines that they "own" or are generally using.